# How to convert the return item into list from array in C#

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I want to convert the output in the list as the method calls in the webservice returns item in the list and here it is returning in the array.

```
catalogueItems = dataService.GetCatalogItemsFromFile(fileFullPath);
```

I need to convert this `dataService.GetCatalogItemsFromFile(fileFullPath)` into a list. How should I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, this one is *without knowing the type*:

```
var list = new[] { dataService.GetCatalogItemsFromFile(fileFullPath) }.ToList()
```

If you know the type this is better:

```
var list = new List<YourType>{ dataService.GetCatalogItemsFromFile(fileFullPath) };
```